# Simplifying division - remove fraction bar

Tags: arithmetic

Let's say we have this equation:
$\frac{a+6b}{a+b}=4$.
How to make fraction bar disappear?

Comment: Do you mean $a+6b=4a+4b$?

Comment: By invoking the spirit of Muhammad ibn Musa al-Khwarizmi and recalling that $x=y$ is equivalent to $Kx=Ky$ for any $K\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. Just multiply both sides by $(a + b)$ and the fraction turns into a linear equation. You can then proceed to solve from there. $$\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{(a+b)} \cdot \frac{a + 6b}{\require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{a + b}} = 4(a+b)$$ $$a+6b = 4(a+b)$$ $$a + 6b = 4a + 4b$$ If you solve for $a$, take out $6b$ and then $4a$ from both sides, whereas if you are solving for $b$, take out $a$ and then $4b$ from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You have $a+6b=4a+4b$ (if $a+b \neq 0$, of course) and then  $3a=2b$

Answer (score 0):

assuming that $$a+b\ne 0$$ we get by multiplying with $a+b$
$$a+6b=4a+4b$$ thus $$a=\frac{2}{3}b$$